# Developer inactive error in beatsmusic

Tags: html, api

Getting the following error while trying Beatsmusic's playground API:

```
{
    "Content-Type": "text/xml",
    "Date": "Sat, 08 Mar 2014 12:59:34 GMT",
    "Server": "Mashery Proxy",
    "Www-Authenticate": "Bearer realm=\"partner.api.beatsmusic.com\"",
    "X-Mashery-Error-Code": "ERR_403_DEVELOPER_INACTIVE",
    "X-Mashery-Responder": "prod-j-worker-us-west-1b-18.mashery.com",
    "Content-Length": "27",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

Comment: What's your code look like?

Comment: This was answered previously here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363627/why-do-i-keep-getting-developer-inactive-errors-when-calling-the-beats-music-a/

Answer (score -1):

Can you send us the code and the request you're making? Developer Inactive through the Mashery proxy typically means you have been rate limited.

Comment: That should be a comment instead of an answer, please.