# Why do I keep getting "developer inactive" errors when calling the Beats Music API?

Tags: beatsmusic

I'm a registered developer, and the error is not repeatable. It will work for one call and then fail again on the exact same call. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jsd Usually you receive the developer inactive error when you've been rate limited or your access token has expired.

Here is some documentation about the developer inactive error: https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/faq/Developer_Inactive

Also, if you have been rate limited you can send an email to beatsplatform@beatsmusic.com and they will raise your limit pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you fail to include the "client_id" parameter in your request.

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if you do not pass the access token correctly.

Some Beats endpoints require the access token to be passed in the `Authorization`header, while others require it to be passed via a querystring parameter.